# Combobox's SelectedValue (or SelectedItem) OneWay binding not working. Any ideas?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox, selectedvalue

In the below window, the Existing Reports combo is bound to an observeablecollection of reportObjects. I have a reportObject property `currentReport` bound to the combo's SelectedValue property, OneWay. However, that's not working when bound in XAML.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding currentReport, Mode=OneWay}"
```

TwoWay binds fine, but I can't do it that way without writing an `undo()` method to the reportObject class. I'm binding the currentReport's properties to the various textboxes for editing. I want to bind OneWay so the source doesn't get changed. The currentReport's properties are all TwoWay bound to the corresponding textboxes so when I update the table in SQL [Save], it'll pull from that object, who's data is current.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding currentReport.reportName, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

All of the properties bound from currentReport to the textboxes work fine as well. The only problem is the OneWay binding from the SelectedValue to the currentReport object. Does anyone have any ideas how to get this to work? I saw there was a bug, but the post I saw was 2009.

[image]

Sorry about the yellow. Not my idea. =)

EDIT: Added this XAML just in case.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding reportsCollection}" SelectionChanged="cboReports_SelectionChanged"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="displayName"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding currentReport, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  x:Name="cboReports" Width="342" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: OneWay updates the target property only when the source property changes.
OneWayToSource updates the source property when the target property changes.

But if you bind the textboxes to the currentReports properties then you actually change the reports properties, do it doesn't really matter how you bind it to your combobox, or did i read something wrong?

Comment: Dude how do you expect to select a different Existing Report if it is not TwoWay?

Comment: @BigL & BalamBalam All I really need is for currentReport to be set to SelectedValue whenever the user selects something from the combo. I don't want changes to currentReport to change the underlying collection, though. I want to merge those changes in when the user saves. currentReport is just a temp object for editing via the textboxes. Make sense? If I two-way bind SelectedValue to currentReport, making changes to currentReport changes the collection. If I do that, I have to write in an undo() method and double the variable count of the reportObject to hold original values until save.

Comment: I can do it in code, but I prefer to use the binding if possible

Comment: So if your selection changes in your combobox you are always creating a new temp currentReport object in the setter of the property you are binding to. Then you set the temps properties and if the user clicks save you merge it to the database. But you still need temp object so your collection never change?

Comment: Exactly. I want the collection to remain unchanged until the user saves. At that point, I'll merge the changes into the collection and the database. I just need the combo to set the currentReport temp object in XAML, since I'm using WPF. I'm new to WPF, so this is probably something relatively easy I'm just overlooking and/or unfamiliar with. We're starting to move into MVVM and I want to get used to more binding, and less setting through events in code-behind.

Comment: Forget about you need to change values - that is a separate problem -clearly you need a better data design.  Start with the UI problem question.  If you want a user to be able to select an item from a combo box then it must have two way binding.  Your first question is SelectedValue="{Binding currentReport, Mode=OneWay}" is failing why.

Comment: The ReportObject is meant to be a simple class so that I can serialize the data from a stored procedure into objects for binding. It works fine for what I'm doing and I don't want to expand the class a great deal to go beyond the scope of what it's meant to accomplish. I can just use the events to set the object for manipulation if I can't do it well through binding - it's accomplishing the same thing. With an MVVM design, we'll have things set up to handle all of this appropriately in XAML - I'm not looking to put a great deal more work into it, unnecessarily. I appreciate all your time, man.

Comment: Do you want to write an answer about the binding being TwoWay to work, so I can give you credit for the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about you need to change values - that is a separate problem - need to review your data design. Start with the UI problem question. If you want a user to be able to select an item from a combo box then it must have two way binding. Your first question is `SelectedValue="{Binding currentReport, Mode=OneWay}"` is failing why?